# Shape of the flattened vector in CNN

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

If I have a max-pooled convolution layer of dimension `(5,5,4)`, means **4 no. of 5x5** feature maps, what will be the shape of the flattened vector after applying flattening operation ?

Is it `(100, 1)` in shape ?